# "right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE ..." при попытке создать 2 таблицы одним запросом

Tags: php

```
$sql='CREATE TABLE admins (
id int(11) auto_increment,
name VARCHAR(50), 
email VARCHAR(50),
pass VARCHAR(50),
login VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
CREATE TABLE pages (
id int(11) auto_increment,
title VARCHAR(25),
meta VARCHAR(50),
content text,
date VARCHAR(8),
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);';
if(!mysql_query($sql)){echo 'Ошибка при создании таблицы в БД!';} else {echo 'Всё прошло отлично, таблица создана!';}
```

Такая ошибка

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE pages( id int(11) auto_increment, title VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, me' at line 9

Если создавать по одной таблице, то работает, но вместе никак. Хотя если через phpmyadmin, то все работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно было перед отправкой вопроса [почитать документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php), в которой прямо под синтаксисом написано:

> `mysql_query()` посылает один запрос **(посылка нескольких запросов не поддерживается)** активной базе данных сервера, на который ссылается переданный дескриптор link_identifier.

Создавайте двумя запросами и все будет хорошо.

ЗЫ: phpMyAdmin пересобирает забросы и разбивает их при необходимости.

Comment: Благодарствую!)